# C++: replicating matlab's interp1 spline interpolation function

Tags: c++, algorithm, matlab, interpolation

Can anyone give me some direction to replicating MATLAB's interp1 function, using spline interpolation? I tried closely replicating the algorithm on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Spline_%28mathematics%29&oldid=288288033#Algorithm_for_computing_natural_cubic_splines), but the results don't really match up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
//MATLAB: interp1(x,test_array,query_points,'spline')

int main(){

    int size = 10;

    std::vector<float> test_array(10);
    test_array[0] = test_array[4] = test_array[8] = 1;
    test_array[1] = test_array[3] = test_array[5] = test_array[7] = test_array[9] = 4;
    test_array[2] = test_array[6] = 7;

    std::vector<float> query_points;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        query_points.push_back(i +.05);

    int n = (size - 1);

    std::vector<float> a(n+1);
    std::vector<float> x(n+1);  //sample_points vector
    for (int i = 0; i < (n+1); i++){
        x[i] = i + 1.0;
        a[i] = test_array[i];
    }

    std::vector<float> b(n);
    std::vector<float> d(n);
    std::vector<float> h(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < (n); ++i)
            h[i] = x[i+1] - x[i];

    std::vector<float> alpha(n);
        for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
            alpha[i] = ((3 / h[i]) * (a[i+1] - a[i])) - ((3 / h[i-1]) * (a[i] - a[i-1]));

    std::vector<float> c(n+1);
    std::vector<float> l(n+1);
    std::vector<float> u(n+1);
    std::vector<float> z(n+1);

    l[0] = 1.0;
    u[0] = z[0] = 0.0;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i){
        l[i] = (2 * (x[i+1] - x[i-1])) - (h[i-1] * u[i-1]);
        u[i] = h[i] / l[i];
        z[i] = (alpha[i] - (h[i-1] * z[i-1])) / l[i];
    }

    l[n] = 1.0;
    z[n] = c[n] = 0.0;

    for (int j = (n - 1); j >= 0; j--){
        c[j] = z[j] - (u[j] * c[j+1]);
        b[j] = ((a[j+1] - a[j]) / h[j]) - ((h[j] / 3) * (c[j+1] + (2 * c[j])));
        d[j] = (c[j+1] - c[j]) / (3 * h[j]);
    }


    std::vector<float> output_array(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        float eval_point = (query_points[i] - x[i]);
        output_array[i] =   a[i] + (eval_point * b[i]) + ( eval_point * eval_point * c[i]) + (eval_point * eval_point * eval_point * d[i]); 
        std::cout << output_array[i] << std::endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So... many... pointers! You don't even leave `main()` why do you need pointers instead of local arrays, or vectors?

Comment: @cyber I used vectors now

Comment: @kandre - Oh God bless you.  I'll trace through your code now as it's more readable.

Answer (score 2):

In hindsight, your code seems to be coded properly referring to the Wikipedia article.  However, there is something you need to know about `interp1` which I don't think you have taken into account when using it to check your answers.

---

MATLAB's `interp1` when you specify the `spline` flag assumes that the end point conditions are **not-a-knot**.  The algorithm specified on Wikipedia is the code for a **natural spline**.

As such, this is probably why your points **do not match up**.  FWIW, consult: http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~turkel/notes/numeng/spline_note.pdf and look at the diagram on the last page.   You'll see that not-a-knot splines and natural splines bear the same shape, but have different y-values when your data consists of just the end points of your spline.  However, should you have data points in between the end points, all of the different kinds of splines (more or less) have the same y values.

For the sake of completeness, here is the figure extracted from the PDF notes I referenced above:

[image]

If you want to use natural splines, use [`csape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/csape.html) instead of `interp1`.  This provides a cubic spline **with end conditions**.  You call `csape` like this:

```
pp = csape(x,y);
```

`x` and `y` are the control points defined for your spline.  By default, this returns a **natural** spline, which is what you're after, and is a struct of type `ppform`.  You can then figure out what the spline evaluates to by using `fnval`:

```
yval = fnval(pp, xval);
```

`xval` and `yval` is the input `x` co-ordinate and the output evaluated for the spline at this particular `x`.

Use this, then check to see if your code matches up with the values provided by `csape`.

---

## Minor Note

You need the Curve Fitting Toolbox in MATLAB to use `csape`.  If you don't have this, then unfortunately this method will not work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Ideally, I will try to figure out the not-a-knot conditions. My code doesn't exactly match the csape function output, while the interp1 and csape results are almost identical, except for the endpoints as you said.

Comment: @kandre OK. I'll take a closer look at your code later tonight. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 0):

I think the `interp1` is supported by MATLAB CODER.
Just use the CODER to generate the C code and you have what you need.